# Nginx config not working

Tags: nginx

I have a pretty basic Nginx config that I can't seem to get to work. I am trying to have it that Nginx will server my node application on `/` and then I have a `/colors` route that doesn't seem to want to work. Yes I know my config file has `/colors/` but that doesn't work either. Both return a 404 not found even when I put the exact html filename/path

I know this has been answered 1000 times before but trying everything I could not get anything to work

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http:/<IP>:<PORT>;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}

location /colors/ {
    root /var/www/colors;
}
```

EDIT**

If I change it so that the colors is done at just `/` then it works but not using `/colors` or `/colors/`

Comment: So what is in the directory you specified, `/var/www/colors/colors`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It is just HTML, CSS and JS files. I have a working config using subdomains instead of location blocks and the `root /var/www/colorsl;` is an exact copy from that config file

Comment: Ops messed up my comment should be `root /var/www/colors;` without the extra `l`

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by setting the `root /var/www;` at the top of my server block and then the following location block.

```
location  /colors/ {
    autoindex on;
    root /var/www;
}
```